# Getting error while trying to run java mail api with aws smtp

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, aws-sdk

I am using aws smtp  for sending mail in java project but when I am running my java project I am getting exception. I copied this program from here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html

But after following same steps as given in this link I am getting this exception so please suggest me what should I do.

Here is my code..

```
public class AmazonSESSample {

static final String FROM = "ansh@artle.in";   // Replace with your "From" address. This address must be verified.
static final String TO = "amit0133@gmail.com";  // Replace with a "To" address. If your account is still in the 
                                                   // sandbox, this address must be verified.

static final String BODY = "This email was sent through the Amazon SES SMTP interface by using Java.";
static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";

// Supply your SMTP credentials below. Note that your SMTP credentials are different from your AWS credentials.
static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "My SMTP username";  // Replace with your SMTP username.
static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = " my SMTP password";  // Replace with your SMTP password.

// Amazon SES SMTP host name. This example uses the US West (Oregon) region.
static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";    

// Port we will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We are choosing port 25 because we will use
// STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
static final int PORT = 587;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 

    // Set properties indicating that we want to use STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
    // The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then the client
    // will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection.
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

    // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    // Create a message with the specified information. 
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
    msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
    msg.setContent(BODY,"text/plain");

    // Create a transport.        
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();

    // Send the message.
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...");

        // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
        transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

        // Send the email.
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Email sent!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close and terminate the connection.
        transport.close();          
    }
}
}
```

Here is **Exception**

```
Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...
The email was not sent.
Error message: null
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:264)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
at awssmtp.AmazonSESSample.main(AmazonSESSample.java:60)
```

Comment: This could be a cause of a bad username / password

Comment: but i copy paste username and password

Comment: i hav created smtp username and smtp password using my amazon server